# How to add a function to Function.prototype in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

I'm trying some basic FP techniques in JavaScript. The `compose` function takes two functions and give out their Composition function. Now I want to make compose a part of the `Function` such that I can chain it with ease.

```
var compose = (func1, func2) => (args => func2(func1(args)));
var square = x => x * x;
var cube = x => x * x * x;
var sixthPower = compose(cube, square);
console.log(sixthPower(2)); // 64
console.log(compose(cube, x => x)(3)); // 27
Function.prototype.compose = function(func) {
  return function(args) {
    func(/* not sure what to write here */)
  }
}
// to make this possible
console.log(square.compose(cube)(3));
```

Comment: What do you mean saying "their Composition function"

Comment: Composition Function of functions f1 and f2 is f3 such that f3(x) = f2(f1(x))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the original `this` reference, so you can use it inside the returned function:

```js
var square = x => x * x;
var cube = x => x * x * x;

Function.prototype.compose = function(func) {
  var self = this;
  return function(args) {
    return func(self(args))
  }
}

console.log(square.compose(cube)(3));
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was looking for, Thanks.

Comment: An alternative would be with the lambda syntax and thus not requiring `this` to be saved to a variable.
`Function.prototype.compose = function(func) { return (args) => func(this(args)) }`

Answer (score 1):

Personally I am against your approach because of the following reasons:

1. Extending on `Function` prototype chain. The `Prototype` js framework is a good example indicating such actions is harmful. Here is an [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice_Extension_of_native_prototypes) from MDN talking about this in detail.
2. Now `compose` is a method instead of a function.

I suggest you check the `compose` function on [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/0.21.0/docs/#compose) (a js functional library)

Comment: Or use function composition in its original sense: `const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x)); comp(cube)(square)(3);`

Comment: @YizhengShen ... Opinion: `Function.prototype` almost from its very beginning did feature `apply` and `call`. Later it even got assigned `bind`. Compose methods provide far more benefit than the latter. `Function.prototype` therefore is the perfect place for standard implementations of e.g. `curry`, `compose`, `before`, `after`, `around` (... only mentioning a few).

Comment: That makes me really sad: _"`Function.prototype` therefore is the perfect place for standard implementations of e.g. curry, compose..."_

Comment: @PeterSeliger I think it's better to favor composition over inheritance, like this: `Object.assign(square, {compose(){...}}`. I also find a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice_Extension_of_native_prototypes) from MDN which talks about the extending native prototypes. PS: I'm not sure about this but I think `apply`, `call`, and `bind` is irrelevant here because they are for language problems, and now with ES6 there are spread operator, arrow function for binding lexical scope to help

Comment: I mean no offense for my following words. If you feel so, I apologize. I think function composition is closer to functional programming function composition than extending `square` with a `compose` function which only have the same name and function as the one in functional programming but lack what's indeed.